# Until + lack of something

Tags: multiple-negation

Long-time listener, first-time caller.
I have a bit of a problem sorting out my sentence and I can't find anything definitive online, so I thought I'd try my luck here.

Which of these two is correct?

> 1. The action will be repeated until there **are not enough** items for another version.
> 2. The action will be repeated until there **are enough** items for another version.

My money is on #1, but I wanted to check because my own language has double negatives so I may be projecting that onto this poor, innocent sentence.

The "action" is copying. Items will be copied until the supply is low enough that a complete copy cannot be made.

Comment: Both are possible, and they mean different things. The first sentence is about exhausting a supply of items, and the second is about creating a supply of items.

Comment: If you tell us exactly what you intend the sentence to mean, we can tell you which version is correct. What 'action' is it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Until there are not enough items:
If you have an unknown quantity (e.g. a big pile of things), let's call them 'widgets', and your job is to pack them into boxes of five, you could take five widgets, pack them in a box, take five more, pack them in a new box, and continue these steps until either all are packed in boxes of five, or you have fewer than five remaining. At this point there are not enough widgets to complete a box.

Until there are enough items:
If you have a machine that ejects one widget each time you pull a lever, you could pull the lever five times. At this point there are enough widgets to fill a box.